# Best Practices for .NET Core 2.0 Kestrell Server Directly Behind AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, .net-core, load-balancing, kestrel-http-server

I'm setting up a production deployment of an API built with .NET Core 2.0 using AWS container services.

A lot of microsoft documentation states Kestral should never be exposed directly to the internet, and should be used with IIS or and NGINX reverse proxy.

1. Would running it directly behind an AWS load balancer be adequate?
2. Is an AWS application load balancer or classic load balancer more suitable?
3. Is an NGINX reverse proxy between the app and the load balancer still necessary?
4. At what layer should http traffic be redirected to https (load balancer, nginx if used, or in kestrel?

Any tips? Best practice?

Comment: This option without a load balancer, just using NGINX may be simpler. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nginx-reverse-proxy-sidecar-container-on-amazon-ecs/

Comment: The reverse proxy is still deemed necessary for Kestrel in dotnet-core 2.0 for a public facing app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: what are you deploying is it an Web API or web application it's nothing to do with your problem but I am facing some issue while deploying Web API so thought to ask you. If  you know anything just let me know below link will help you to understand more about the issue. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232360/webapi-net-core-2-0-on-aws-ec2-linux-deploying-issue